# Single threaded PyMPI application running multiple processes

Tags: python, process, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a `Python` application distributed onto multiple nodes with `PyMPI`. I know for a fact that the application is single threaded b/c I tried making it multi threaded then rolled back to single threaded when I realized the global interpreter lock prevents `Python` from being truly multi threaded. I also know that my application does not launch any other processes.

**Single Threaded. Single Process**

When I launch my application on `n` nodes, and I log into each node and issue the command `top` the number of `Python` processes is always as follows:

```
node | Python Processes 
-----------------------
 0           8
 1           2
 2           1
 3           1
 4           1
...
...
...
 n           1
```

I suspect that `PyMPI` is using the extra 7 processes on node 0. I have no idea what node 1 is using process 2 for.  My system administrator is upset over some other issues, but this is one of them. I would like to at the very least explain to him why the breakdown of processes per node is `8, 2, 1, 1, ..., 1`. Can anyone confirm that it is indeed `PyMPI` that is using up the extra 7 processes in node 0 and the extra 1 process in node 1.

Comment: We'll need more information than a process count.   How do you launch your program?  Do you spawn mpi tasks within the program?

Comment: @JonathanDursi I run it like so `mpirun -n 5 python main.py -MPI` what's an mpi task? An mpi rank?

Comment: Yes - do you call MPI_Comm_spawn or do anything else that creates new MPI tasks during the program?

Comment: @JonathanDursi no, definitely nothing like that. Does MPI launch a different process in the root node to deal with different ranks?